# wp_head wordpress function doesn't accept style from other function

Tags: php, css, wordpress

Trying to add styling code for background image using WordPress wp_head hook but it doesn't work. Here is the code: (when code is used inside f1 function  I get "error" message but outside f1 function code works fine and gets url for background image correctly, so problem is with wp_head. Any thoughts?

```
function f1() {  
?> <style>
.boxes{ 
  background-image: 
  url(
<?php
$images = rwmb_meta( 'f3' );
if ( !empty( $images ) ) {
  foreach ( $images as $image ) {
    echo $image['url'];
  }
}
else {
  echo 'error';
}
?>
);
}</style>
<?php
} 
add_action( 'wp_head', 'f1');
```

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: No error message, just "error" as else statement result. Variable $image is empty when it is inside f1 functions but it is not empty outside of that function.

Comment: Ok, so this means the $images is empty, so `rwmb_meta( 'f3' )` returns nothing. Can you try vardump `rwmb_meta( 'f3' )`, and check if it containers anything? Could you also share the code for `rwmb_meta`, I guess it is some custom plugin function? But I do not know what it does :)

Comment: Yes it contains everything needed, just outside f1 function. It is custom function for metabox plugin

Answer (score 0):

Try passing in the post_id to your rwmb_meta() call

```
function f1() { ?> 
    <style>
    .boxes{ 
      background-image: 
      url(
    <?php
    global $post;
    $images = rwmb_meta( 'f3', array(), $post->ID );
    if ( !empty( $images ) ) {
      foreach ( $images as $image ) {
        echo $image['url'];
      }
    }
    else {
      echo 'error';
    }
    ?>
    );
    }</style>
    <?php
} 
add_action( 'wp_head', 'f1');
```

Comment: Doesn't help. Also it should be that way as it is recommended by metabox plugin https://metabox.io/

Comment: If you are using `rwmb_meta` inside the loop you can omit the $args and $post_id parameter but outside the loop you will want to use them. https://metabox.io/docs/get-meta-value/

Comment: Sorry for dumb question but what exactly should be there instead of question marks: rwmb_meta( 'f3', 'url=?', 'name of custom post type?' );

Comment: The arguments are explained here: https://metabox.io/docs/get-meta-value/#section-arguments However if you have tried the code I posted and that is still not working please post the var_dump of $images

Comment: inside loop var_dump($images); have all arguments that it should have but outside of loop it is null. Maybe I didn't add arguments correctly, this is how I added rwmb_meta( 'f3', 'url', 'customposttypename' );

Comment: Look at the code I posted... `global $post;` followed by `$images = rwmb_meta( 'f3', array(), $post->ID );`